# Killed error while removing watermark in PDF & Merging the images to get PDF in VsCode. [ OS : Ubuntu ]

Tags: python, pypdf, pdf2image

Lat two lines of my output shown in my Terminal

Adding TEXT TOP @ LEFT CORNER for AP ECET 2020 Electronics and Communication Engineering September 14, 2020 Shift 2 English Question Paper
Killed

Removing the Watermark step from pdf is working smoothly, but when it comes to merge the images, output shown is KIILED.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you're having a bug. You need to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have memory errors, this library is not optimised for merging pages. I hope this improves in future